# The Eclipse XML Graphical Layout Editor for Android SDK

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, user-interface, textview

I am trying to use the Graphical Layout editor to make my app, so far so good but now I am in this problem:
[image: Textview wont go up]

I want the grey small textview to go a little higher but no matter what I do this isnt happening. How do those apps in the market have such beautiful GUIs when I can barely create a simple one? What are they using that I am not? :P Thanks.

Comment: Start using xml and code it, Eclipse layout editor is still not up to the mark

Comment: Thats my problem, even if I do add the margin-top or margin-bottom attributes the thing doesnt budge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, To fine tune the UI, you will eventually have to edit the generated XML. It would be good if you start getting your hands dirty with the XMLs. Please post the XML and then anyone would be able to suggest what changes to make.

I think you would probably reduce the padding or margin of the textview above.

Comment: Should I use the dp or another form of measurement for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the XML and decreasing the top margin of the text? Or decreasing the bottom margin of the view above the text?